# Bazel Platforms is trying to find C++ toolchains to compile Java

Tags: java, bazel

I am trying to use Platforms functionality for logic which packages a java application in a tarball containing platform-specific JDK binaries and JVM flags. The produced java artifact itself is obviously platform-agnostic, so I was expecting that this command would work out of the box:

```
bazel build --platforms=//bazel/platforms:platform_linux_x86_64 //src/...
```

But looks like bazel is trying to find C++ toolchain to compile the project:

```
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target //src/main/java/com/xgen/mongot/util:lib: No matching toolchains found for types @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type. Maybe --incompatible_use_cc_configure_from_rules_cc has been flipped and there is no default C++ toolchain added in the WORKSPACE file? See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10134 for details and migration instructions.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to specify a no-op toolchain or somehow hint bazel that there is no c++ code to compile?

Comment: It might help if you could share the relevant snippets of `//src/main/java/com/xgen/mongot/util:BUILD.bazel` otherwise I can only guess at what is going on.

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question? I am hitting the same issue.

Comment: No, I did not. I'm having a hard time finding any answers to non-trivial bazel questions, the community seems to be too small